# LocalDateTime adiantando duas horas ao submeter formulário

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-jpa

Quando eu vou submeter um formulário com a classe *LocalDateTime* gerenciando os campos de hora e data, ela adianta duas horas. Constatei esse adiantamento com o horário do meu computador.

**Código:**

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.algaworks.brewer.model.Venda;
import com.algaworks.brewer.repository.Vendas;

@Service
public class CadastroVendaService {

    @Autowired
    private Vendas vendas;

    @Transactional
    public void salvar(Venda venda) {
        if (venda.isNova()) {
            venda.setDataCriacao(LocalDateTime.now());
        }

        if (venda.getDataEntrega() != null) {
            venda.setDataHoraEntrega(LocalDateTime.of(venda.getDataEntrega(), 
                venda.getHorarioEntrega() != null ? venda.getHorarioEntrega() : LocalTime.now()));
        }

        vendas.save(venda);
    }
}
```

Comment: Informe o `zoneId` ao capturar o valor. Ex.: `venda.setDataCriacao(LocalDateTime.now( ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("BET") ));`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-

Comment: A diferença é entre quais horários? O do seu computador com o banco, o da JVM com o banco, ou algum outro? A JVM geralmente usa o mesmo fuso do computador no qual está rodando, mas isso pode ser mudado via código e/ou configuração, o mesmo vale para o banco. Se puder **[edit]** a pergunta colocando alguns exemplos e imprimindo os valores dos `LocalTime` e `LocalDateTime` gerados, além do valor gravado no banco (que o select retorna, e o que o Java retorna ao fazer a consulta), além do timezone configurado em cada um (`ZoneId.systemDefault()` e o timezone do banco), talvez dê para ajudar mais

Comment: @ValdeirPsr `SHORT_IDS.get("BET")` é um [atalho para `America/Sao_Paulo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS). Só que este valor é uma `String`, e `now` recebe um `ZoneId`, então o correto seria `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"))` (apesar de `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("BET")))` também funcionar, mas acho que passar "America/Sao_Paulo" diretamente fica mais sucinto e menos confuso). Mas p/ mim não ficou claro se o problema é exatamente esse (*provavelmente* é por causa do timezone, mas não sei se só isso resolve)

Comment: @hkotsubo Verdade. Grato pela correção. Acredito que o código esteja noutro servidor (talvez numa máquina virtual), por isso a diferença.